# Manage top header of web page if monitor screen is too big

Tags: html, css

I have header in the top section of browser. Css for it is:
.top section {

```
position: absolute;
height: 83px;
background: #fcfcfc;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
width: 100%;
min-width: 1000px;
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
```

}

I generally use 100% width. It suits laptops and small monitors. But if monitor screen is too big like 21 inches, it will not look good. So I want, that top section header should not be greater than some maximum width. I can use 'maz-width: px' css attribute, but problem with it is, it will not have symmetrical margins on left and right side. This again looks bad. So what should I do to have maximum size defined, but with proper margins so that page looks good in case screen size is big.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be symmetrically in the center, use `text-align:center` for the `body` and `margin:auto` for the top section, and disable the `position:absolute`. Now you can set a `max-width`.
Consult [this site](http://dev.art-arium.appspot.com). The box thing in the middle has a `min-width` set (no `max-width`, though), but it stays symmetrically in the center even with scaling and browser window resize. Check the CSS used for that box, and use similar css for your heading.

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries, set behavior based on width: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

Comment: I  am currently looking for css and html solution. Thank you very much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

How about using something like the [Less framework](http://lessframework.com) or it's successor [FramelessGrid](http://framelessgrid.com)?